# AJAX request not working as expected on first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery AJAX for my login system.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.session.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Login() {
    var postData = JSON.stringify({
      "username": $("#txtUsername").val(),
      "password": $("#txtPassword").val(),
      "linenumber": $("#ddlLineNum").val()
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "frmLogin.aspx/MyMethod",
      data: postData,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: callbackfunction,
      error: function(msg) {
        alert('ERROR');
      }
    });
  }

  function callbackfunction(result) {
    alert('in call back method');
    if (result.d == "WrongPassword") {
      alert(result.d);
    }

    if (result.d == "Currect Password") {
      alert(username);
      //$.session.set('UserName',username);
      //$.session.set('lineNumber', linenumber);
      //alert($.session.get("UserName"));
      window.location.href = 'Inventory.aspx';
    }
  }
</script>
```

If I click on my login button for the first time this `callbackfunction` is not working (`alert('in call back method')` is not displaying). When I click for the second time  the `alert` is shown.

Can anyone help me out to fix this issue.

```js
if (username == string.Empty)
  return "UserName is Empty";
if (password == string.Empty)
  return "Password is Empty";
if (linenumber == "Please Select")
  return "Line Number is Empty";

DataTable dtLogin = DBLayer.spUserMasterSelect(username);
if (dtLogin.Rows.Count > 0) {
  if (dtLogin.Rows[0]["PASSWORD"].ToString() != password) {
    return "WrongPassword";
  } else {
    return "Currect Password";
  }
} else {
  return "Invalid UserName";
}
```

REQUEST AND RESPONSE IS 
frmlogin.aspx
header file is 
Request URL: http://localhost:57075/frmLogin.aspx
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:57075
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3698
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 09:44:44 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcQ3VycmVudCBQcm9qZWN0c1xNVFMtV0NQTVxXQ1BNIE5FVyAtIEpxdWVyeSBhbmQgQWpheFxUQ0lMaVdNU1xmcm1Mb2dpbi5hc3B4?=
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 559
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:57075
Origin: http://localhost:57075
Referer: http://localhost:57075/frmLogin.aspx
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
__LASTFOCUS: 
__VIEWSTATE: cGCxGPZDpgAFMuHbrg1A53vAaM0BzvQjz7MfEimIFx+HJKP+qBDaZHi1pnNTxGprZm35gQjfw5qALYaMZBThSWH2j2GnHiOjHU5BnC3D+WluwvbeyevsZenrwCBd06esBm49ZCc5MY+RcTNeiwhGRQ==
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: 0C51E059
__EVENTTARGET: 
__EVENTARGUMENT: 
__EVENTVALIDATION: ikyLG2JZUj1pDNj+/nM4K0teZ/HT96A1W0NQ1y2qhTATegzDSkvfPZrk6PyZo7DF6bQFKOEu+/zf+bTdFHz6UqEnzcMvq+mCZhBQK3Wab92NRtB5w4TllqDq3gbdv0pjeyrXWtmfUexxo76PdXEAoZ1sDBFHhqsdzXMwwX62mFLhmiPoYUmwR1iWxky++B4F+rP4jxQtsvhUnJG8qELgzQ==
txtUsername: ADMIN
txtPassword: ADMIN
ddlLineNum: 1

this is for second time
Request URL: http://localhost:57075/frmLogin.aspx
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:57075
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3708
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 09:46:36 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcQ3VycmVudCBQcm9qZWN0c1xNVFMtV0NQTVxXQ1BNIE5FVyAtIEpxdWVyeSBhbmQgQWpheFxUQ0lMaVdNU1xmcm1Mb2dpbi5hc3B4?=
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 506
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:57075
Origin: http://localhost:57075
Referer: http://localhost:57075/frmLogin.aspx
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
__VIEWSTATE: zG8/UiXsuL3e8xOkmL3OW4uIsVjWX307lugZuGNqFSBzejHQxN86sg9lllvaWrJIJZ6/TRi1lbGpJc9XiurbTZecE0GINMpyzSrrAvaiRmQt8HV1USp55SGw6gF5aVtHtFmkgZe3xFUr06SaXhbiwQ==
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: 0C51E059
__EVENTVALIDATION: 3rl06ckIZwSoQBBJWRONyuPdNovib37nYRGrZNW1FBCOUf8dsDPSTDUpW8uHMlRTMqd8OPKKXiqaGT/DyI51YJplGnyaoB4E4OuBFX43tL+p4HtbWZf2p8kURyNxUdELR7w1ubkiC0GIkkllT1VqrjmkLeuhnkan7xGgiqjj/V/R++NPQWOD+/B0AM7qJeeheYM2UaLv5ZRuUNc1GnKURg==
txtUsername: ADMIN
txtPassword: admin
ddlLineNum: 1

Comment: `Currect` - heads up that might be a typo.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints on the server side and debugged through when the AJAX request is made?

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab) and get the request and response for the first request that doesn't work, and the second one that does. Include all four of them in your question.

Comment: @mjwills i have debugged server side code. and both time it is returning same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: @mjwills i am using encryption for storing the password in the database.

Comment: You should be salting and hashing, not encrypting. I'd suggest reading the link.

Comment: "*I click on my login button for the first time*" - please include relevant markup in your question.

Comment: @mjwills i am not able to present request and response data as it is having much lines. but i have analyzed there is no difference

Comment: I am 95% sure there is a difference. Nonetheless, we can't help without a [mcve].

Comment: Please format your question properly. I've already edited it for you once, I'm not going to do it again.

Answer (score -1):

Consider catching a failure from your AJAX post request. It might help troubleshoot for your click on your login button for the first time.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "frmLogin.aspx/MyMethod",
  data: postData,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: callbackfunction,
  failure: failureFxn,
  error: function(msg) {
    alert('ERROR');
  }
});

function failureFxn() {
  console.log('failure');
}
```

Comment: tried with above code. still no failure . console.log is empty

Comment: There is no `failure` property of `$.ajax`. There is only the `error` callaback which the OP is already using (although it could be used more effectively by checking what `msg` contains). Please read docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.